# how to solve argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2 error of pyautogui pixel match method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

```
def perfect_click(name, r, g, b):    # Performs a click after checking for loaded image
    location = None
    image_file = name

    while location is None:
        try:
            location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image_file)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    coordinates = pyautogui.center(location)
    x, y = coordinates
    print(coordinates)
    pixel = False
    while pixel is False:
        try:
            pixel = pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(x, y, (r, g, b), tolerance=10)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    pyautogui.click(coordinates)
```

the above code is supposed to check if the button is clickable and then click it by checking for pixel colour as unclickable buttons are generally a bit dull and pyautogui's locate on screen dosen't work there.
I't giving me this error, can somebody please help me to resolve this? I really tried everything I could!

`argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2`

Comment: Which line does it error on?

Comment: Says no line in the error but I think its of pixel = ..

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I just converted the values of the location in integers:

```
x=location.top
x=int(x)
```